# Scheduled thread vs Threading.Timer in .NET

Tags: .net, multithreading

I need to execute code in a separate thread from the UI in VB.NET. The code needs to be executed every few seconds and also when the user performs a certain activity. The thread will perform tasks that will change the UI. Should I use a normal thread and then use a Windows.Forms.Timer Timer to run this thread every few seconds or will a System.Threading.Timer class work better?

Also, the code the thread must execute comprises of multiple functions. Should I execute all of the function on the same thread or considering splitting them up in a few threads?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you change your UI Windows.Forms.Timer is the best way, because the Timer-Elapsed Event will be raised in the ui thread and therefore you don't have to change to it. If you want to make long lasting actions before changing ui, then I would prefer using the Threading.Timer. I would make the long lasting action and then switch to the UI thread (via Invoke) and change the ui. This would make the UI more reactive to users actions.

Comment: Thanks, I'll try that. The thread takes about 1.5 seconds to execute so it has to be in a separate thread otherwise the program is not very responsive.